# Python, How to make one data frame from two

Tags: python, dataframe

1)I have two data frames. They have the same amount and name of columns. How can I unite it into one data frame?
I need smth like np.vstack for data frames.
2) I have data frame with column 'Sex', where are 'male' and 'female'. How can I change values 'male' to 1 and 'female' to 0 (without loops)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you read https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True).replace({'Sex': {'male': 1, 'female': 0}})
```